# Why is there an f in the parameters of this method: os.listdir(f'{PATH}valid')?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was taking the fast.ai course and came across this snippet of code (in Python 3):

```
PATH = "data/dogscats/"
os.listdir(f'{PATH}valid')
```

This returns the list of the files in the directory `data/dogscats/valid`, like I expected. However, I don't understand what purpose the "f" in front of `'{PATH}valid'` serves. When removed, the code throws a "FileNotFound" error. Why is the "f" there? It's not even part of the string? I know this might be an elementary question, but it's something I'd love to understand.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's a format string, introduced in Python 3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's new in Python 3.6, introduced in [PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/), and it's called an `f-string` for *formatted string literal*. There are many ways to do similar things in Python; the oldest is the standard string interpolation using `%`, then the string `.format()` method, and now `f-strings`, for e.g.:

```
>>> '%svalid' % 'data/dogscats/'
'data/dogscats/valid'
>>> '{PATH}valid'.format(PATH='data/dogscats/')
'data/dogscats/valid'
>>> PATH = 'data/dogscats/'
>>> f'{PATH}valid'
'data/dogscats/valid'
```

It can be more than just a substitution of values however, as you can actually evaluate expressions as well:

```
>>> x = 5
>>> f'The value of {x}^2 is {x**2}'
'The value of 5^2 is 25'
```

From the [docs on `f-strings`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings):

> A *formatted string literal* or *f-string* is a string literal that is prefixed with `'f'` or `'F'`. These strings may contain replacement fields, which are expressions delimited by curly braces `{}`. While other string literals always have a constant value, formatted strings are really expressions evaluated at run time.

Answer (score 2):

`f-string` is really an expression evaluated at runtime, not a constant value. In Python, an f-string is a literal string, prefixed with `f`, which contains expressions inside braces. The expressions are replaced with their values.

So, `f'{PATH}valid'` gets evaluated to `data/dogscats/valid`.